# Why do I get the following error when using 'conda update --all' and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm running conda 4.3.18 on win-64 with python 3.6.0. Until recently I've been running separate virtual environments successfully using conda and had no problems. Today I can't update anything in any environment. I get the following error when using `conda update --all` for example:

```
Fetching package metadata ...........ERROR requests.packages.urllib3.connection:
_match_hostname(360): Certificate did not match expected hostname: conda.binstar
.org. Certificate: {'subject': ((('commonName', 'anaconda.com'),),), 'subjectAlt
Name': [('DNS', 'anaconda.com'), ('DNS', 'anacondacloud.com'), ('DNS', 'anaconda
cloud.org'), ('DNS', 'binstar.org'), ('DNS', 'wakari.io')]}

CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://conda.binstar.org/menpo/win-64/r
epodata.json>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

SSLError(SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'conda.binstar.org' doesn't match e
ither of 'anaconda.com', 'anacondacloud.com', 'anacondacloud.org', 'binstar.org'
, 'wakari.io'",),),)
```

I'm somewhat new to conda and it is unclear to me how I should fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try temporarily disabling the check:

```
CONDA_SSL_VERIFY=false conda update --all
```

Ref: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5170

On Windows try running

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
conda update --all
```

Comment: Thanks for your help John. Unfortunately I get: 'CONDA_SSL_VERIFY' is not recognized as in internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @347: Oh I see you're on Windows.  Try running `conda config --set ssl_verify false` then `conda update --all`.

Comment: Thanks, I should have picked that up! That solution worked for me. I checked the SSL certificate for https://conda.binstar.org/. It's in date but isn't valid, a mismatch with their sub-domains I think. Thanks again.